# In H. P. Lovecraft's work - how is "The Prolonged of Life" understood when it comes to meaning?

Tags: meaning, literature, archaicisms

I'm translating one of the stories into my mother tongue and I'm struggling with the name of one of the elder gods - "The Prolonged of Life". I do not really understand how this is meant to be interpreted - the one (or ones) that have prolonged life? That one that prolongs life? The adjective confuses me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The answers so far proposed do make sense; however, I don't know what keeps one from interpreting this as "one that is endowed besides their own nature (what other than divine? and so not associated with life) with the possibility of experiencing life"; to refer again to biblical phenomena, which has been done in an answer, this is in fact the nature of the Christian God descended among men as a life form, the very form of a human being. It follows, in my opinion, that before rushing to conclusions it might be useful to reexamine the context (what comes after in the book might provide clues).

Comment: The locution is literary in style. Compare  "the swift *of foot*", i.e. the swift-footed, i.e. fast runners. "The prolonged of life" are those whose lives are prolonged. The long-lived. Not the *prolongers* of life.

Comment: The comments and answers on this page are all over the place. I would not accept any of these (including mine) without further research on Lovecraft, religion, and — most of all (for this site) — past participle adjectives vs. the passive voice.

Comment: Or the hard of hearing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short story that you are trying to translate is called ***Through the Gates of the Silver Key*** by H.P. Lovecraft. Lovecraft was an early to mid 20th century author of cosmic horror works. "The Prolonged of Life" refers specifically to a character in the story. It is part of the Lovecraft mythos. This is not an easy story to translate.

The character 'Umr at-Tawil also called Tawil at’Umr is known as the Most Ancient One. Lovecraft claims that 'Umr at-Tawil means "the prolonged of life" in Arabic. That is probably incorrect, as Lovecraft describes lots of mysterious events, books, phenomena etc. that he introduces in his stories as meaning something in the Arabic language even though they don't.

‘Umr at-Tawil is the entity that the story's protagonist, Randolph Carter,  encounters in his dreams. This is a [decent description but not authoritative](https://lovecraftianscience.wordpress.com/2017/02/25/through-the-gates-of-the-silver-key-chapter-iii-umr-at-tawil-and-the-application-of-string-theory/):

> Carter meets a heavily cloaked humanoid entity. Carter states, “…it
> seemed to belong to an order of being far outside the merely physical
> in organization and faculties.” This being was the “frightful Guide
> and Guardian of the Gate,” known as the Ancient One, Umr at-Tawil or
> the Prolonged of Life.
>
> Very little is known about Umr at-Tawil but its title as Ancient One
> and the Prolonged of Life indicates that it has existed for a very
> long time, perhaps since the creation of our Universe. The being
> appears to be the way or guide to the Ultimate Gate, which based on
> the tale so far must be “outside” or beyond the known Universes bound
> in Space-Time. Additionally, Umr at-Tawil was one of a number of such
> gatekeepers, which appeared to Carter as seated on a series of vaguely
> hexagonal pillars.

To answer the question, in the context of the Lovecraft story, Umr at-Tawil may be **BOTH** long-lived **AND** have the ability to prolong the lives of others. Umr at-Tawil is definitely long-lived or possibly immortal; however, Randolph Carter's life is prolonged by Umr at-Tawil.

Answer (score 12):

To add to Glaadrial's answer on the literal meaning of the term, Lovecraft intends a parallel to "[The Ancient of Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_of_Days)" (Daniel 7:9), one of the names of the Judeo-Christian God from the Bible.

If your audience are likely to be familiar with the Book of Daniel, keeping this parallel in your translation - finding words that mean "The One Whose Life is Prolonged" and are similar to those in your preferred version of the Bible - might be a good idea.

Answer (score 12):

The locution is literary in style.

Compare

- **the swift of foot**, i.e. the swift-footed, [those whose feet are swift], i.e. fast runners.

The prolonged of life" are those whose lives are prolonged. The long-lived. [Those whose lives are longer than the norm.] Not the prolongers of life.                                                           –     TimR

Answer (score 8):

> …the one (or ones) that have [a] prolonged life

This. It is an example of using a character trait as a title. Someone who has lived longer than usual can be described as being prolonged of life. The title could be used to name a group who share a similar trait; using it to describe a single god also works.

*Edited to add citations, etc., at the behest of Community Bot*

Building on Tevildo’s guidance suggesting a biblical parallel, [biblegateway.com](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Daniel%207:9) provides a list of English translations of the term *Ancient of Days* as it appears in Daniel 7:9.

Moreover, if there is an intended allusion to biblical phenomena, [2 Kings 20:5-6](https://www.biblestudytools.com/2-kings/passage/?q=2+kings+20:5-6) describes the situation in which Hezekiah has his life prolonged by God. Perhaps this story can provide context for the source material that the OP endeavors to translate.  In his 1964 general conference address, Presiding Bishop John H. Van den berg, explores the lesson of the Hezekiah’s experience ([Hezekiah’s Life Prolonged](https://www.thechurchnews.com/1994/7/16/23256785/hezekiahs-life-prolonged)).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, the ones whose lives have been prolonged.

Comment: @Lambie: No? Wouldn’t “those whose lives have been prolonged” by some external means not display the trait until such a time that they have actually lived longer than usual? In the context where it is the proper name/title of a god, as it is in this question, it seems more reasonable surmise that the condition is inherent or has already manifested?

Answer (score 3):

According to theologian Robert M. Price, “The Prolonged of Life” refers to “The Most Ancient One,” which suggests that it means someone who has lived a long time.

<sub>Source: [*Holy Fable Volume IV: A Critical Study of Modern Scriptures*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Holy_Fable_Volume_IV/C9_hDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The%20Prolonged%20of%20Life%22&pg=PT405&printsec=frontcover) (Robert M. Price, 2020)</sub>

Comment: Or just from the text. The story is "Through the Gates of the Silver Key", it's on-line, and the quote is: "For He is 'Umr At-Tawil, the Most Ancient One, which the scribe rendereth as the Prolonged of Life." Oddly, Lovecraft's co-writer was _also_ named Price.